# Есть ли какой-то инструмент для визуализации JSON

Tags: json

Довольно часто сталкиваюсь в подобными JSON ответами

```
{"query":{"ids":[69078571],"preset":"tech_platforms","dimensions":["ym:s:browser"],"metrics":["ym:s:visits","ym:s:users","ym:s:bounceRate","ym:s:pageDepth","ym:s:avgVisitDurationSeconds"],"sort":["-ym:s:visits"],"date1":"2021-01-10","date2":"2021-01-16","limit":100,"offset":1,"group":"Week","auto_group_size":"1","attr_name":"","quantile":"50","offline_window":"21","attribution":"LastSign","currency":"RUB","adfox_event_id":"0"},"data":[{"dimensions":[{"icon_id":"3","icon_type":"browser","name":"Firefox","id":"3"}],"metrics":[1.0,1.0,100.0,1.0,0.0]},{"dimensions":[{"icon_id":"6","icon_type":"browser","name":"Google Chrome","id":"6"}],"metrics":[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,16.0]},{"dimensions":[{"icon_id":"14","icon_type":"browser","name":"UCWEB","id":"14"}],"metrics":[1.0,1.0,100.0,1.0,0.0]}],"total_rows":3,"total_rows_rounded":false,"sampled":false,"contains_sensitive_data":false,"sample_share":1.0,"sample_size":3,"sample_space":3,"data_lag":127,"totals":[3.0,3.0,66.66666667,1.0,5.33333333],"min":[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0],"max":[1.0,1.0,100.0,1.0,16.0]}
```

Выше приведённый пример - ответ от Яндекс директа.

Дальше необходимо десериализовать подобный ответ. Очень неудобно, ещё опыта нет, приходится переписывать в блокнот, выделять объекты пробелами и Enter'om

Наверняка есть инструмент, который это сделает за меня

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=json+formatter Выбирайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать Notepad++ с плагином JSON Viewer.
Заменяет обычный блокнот в принципе + расширяет возможности очень прилично за счет плагинов.
[image: Notepad++]